# How to get the data of a query in arangojs

Tags: arangodb, arangojs

Hello I'm using arangojs, created a database, added data to the collection `beusers`.

Now I want to read the added data. In ArangoDB I can do so using the query

```
FOR user IN beusers
FILTER user.password == '3670747394' && user.email == '3817128089'
RETURN user
```

Doing

```js
const user = await usedDB.parse(aql`
        FOR user IN ${usersCol.name}
        FILTER user.password == ${hashedPassword} && user.email == ${hashedEmail}
        RETURN user
`)
console.log(user)
```

in arangojs I get

```
{
  error: false,
  code: 200,
  parsed: true,
  collections: [],
  bindVars: [ 'value2', 'value0', 'value1' ],
  ast: [ { type: 'root', subNodes: [Array] } ]
}
```

The example in the [readme](https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs) got me only so far.

What am I missing? How can I read the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`Database.query()`](https://arangodb.github.io/arangojs/latest/classes/_database_.database.html#query) to get a cursor ([`ArrayCursor`](https://arangodb.github.io/arangojs/latest/classes/_cursor_.arraycursor.html)) and then you want to return the value in the cursor's result list (for example using [`ArrayCursor.all()`](https://arangodb.github.io/arangojs/latest/classes/_cursor_.arraycursor.html#all)).

So the code would look like this:

```js
const cursor = await usedDB.query(aql`
  FOR user IN ${usersCol.name}
    FILTER user.password == ${hashedPassword} && user.email == ${hashedEmail}
    RETURN user
`);
console.log(await cursor.all()); // returns array of users
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I just used the wrong method there. Correct would've been:

```js
const user = await db.executeTransaction(
    {
      read: ['beusers'],
    },
    `
      function() {
        // This code will be executed inside ArangoDB!
        const { query } = require("@arangodb");
        return query\`
            FOR user IN ${col.name}
            FILTER user.password == "${stringHash(
              passedUser.password,
            )}" && user.email == "${stringHash(passedUser.email)}"
            RETURN user
          \`.toArray()[0];
      }
    `,
  )
```